# Saving not cached offline images in Firefox

Tags: firefox

I want to save the images from a page in Firefox that have been open for a couple of days. The problem is that neither the page nor the images are available anymore online. The images where dynamically generated and not cached.

The only way I can think of is by making a screenshot and then cutting out each invidual image. Isn't there a better way of getting the data from the browsers memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be fastest to just take screenshots, but I would avoid the method you had in mind. Taking 1 shot and then cutting out separate shots is just more work. You can grab [Jing](http://www.jingproject.com/) and cut your selection right from the screen:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only ways I know of pulling images out of Firefox is via the Page Info (and then under Media) OR dragging the image out of the window onto a file destination. (or about:cache of course)

I just tried this with a file from my local webserver and it looks like you will have to do the screenshot method (firefox tries to grab a new copy when you drag or save from Page Info).

You could theoretically dump Firefox's process memory and wade through it, but it'd probably be faster to just screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/mozilla_cache_viewer.html

Description

MozillaCacheView is a small utility that reads the cache folder of Firefox/Mozilla/Netscape Web browsers, and displays the list of all files currently stored in the cache. For each cache file, the following information is displayed: URL, Content type, File size, Last modified time, Last fetched time, Expiration time, Fetch count, Server name, and more. 
You can easily select one or more items from the cache list, and then extract the files to another folder, or copy the URLs list to the clipboard.

There are equivalents for IE, Opera etc. Useful if you have closed your browser and want them too!